# PHPMailer 500 Error on Session Variables

Tags: php, session-variables

I am using PHPMailer on a project I am working on, and on my localhost it works like a charm! But I am using a friend's server to test the site for different devices. As I'm waiting for more content to plug in, I'm doing some work on the functionality of the site.

I wrote a script to go along with PHPMailer that does everything I need it to do, but on the top of the page, before my doctype, I have set a couple of session variables. After hours of tinkering with it, I have come to realize that is what's causing my 500 error. I've tried moving them into the head section, but the only thing that (kind of) works on the server is commenting them out completely. But then, when I try to submit the mail, it goes to the PHP file and never redirects to the home page like it's supposed to.

Any ideas on how to fix this? If it helps, here's the part of my code that's messing things up:

`$errors = isset($_SESSION['errors']) ? $_SESSION['errors'] : [];
$fields = isset($_SESSION['fields']) ? $_SESSION['fields'] : [];`

UPDATE: Here is the image for the phpinfo...[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you call [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) before using the SESSION_[] super global variable ?

session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

Comment: Yep. I have the session_start(); at the very top and unset for both of those variables at the very bottom (after the </html>). For some reason it's just those two lines that are giving me trouble. If I comment them out, the page loads just fine, but then the form doesn't work. It just stays on the mailer.php page without redirecting back like it should. But it works perfectly in my localhost. Would it help if I posted the whole PHP file and the snippets at the top and bottom of the HTML?

Comment: As you said it was working well on your local server

use phpinfo() and check the session.* settings.

Maybe the informations is forced to be stored in cookies and your browser do not accept cookies, something like that.

Check that first and come back with the results.

You can also do a print_r($_SESSION); to have a dump of this variable and see the content....

Regarding your phpinfo(), does the session.save_path is a valid one? Does your webserver has write access to this directory?

Hope this helps.

Comment: It looks like the browser is accepting cookies, session save path is in /tmp and the web server does have write access. I couldn't get print_r($_SESSION); to work though.

Comment: I tried to move them again one more time into the body this time, right above the contact form. No luck...

Comment: 500 Error is the error thrown by web server. Can you please check what php has to say about the error.

You have to track the php error message. Check error_reporting, error_log and log_errors directives in phpinfo().

Comment: Also please post the screenshot of the phpinfo session section.

What is the value of "session.save_handler" is it "files" or "user"

Comment: No value for error_reporting and error_log, but log_errors is off. How do I turn that on? I tried echo error_reporting(E_ALL); both before and after the session variables and nothing came up.

Comment: It won't let me post the image, but the value was files.

Comment: Write 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

before Session variable. 

or if you have access to php.ini uncomment following lines

; display_errors = On
; error_reporting = E_ALL

Comment: I don't have access to the php.ini file, but I put those two lines in before the session variables and I'm still just getting the same message: "Uh-oh, something went wrong! Error Code: 500 "

Comment: It let me post the image now, if you can take a look at it and see if there's anything wrong with that setup? Now, instead of the 500 error, it's just giving me a blank page.

Comment: Please try to print session_id() and copy the session id. Now go to /tmp directory and check whether any file contains the same session id in its name. For example if the session id is 58a2lrf74k9orvrsvk3og57j60 then the file name might look like sess
_58a2lrf74k9orvrsvk3og57j60 . Please also check whether you are getting the same session id in the cookie tab of the firebug 'PHPSESSID' key.

Comment: I am getting the same session ID (according to firebug, not using any cookies though). However, the only way I can get the page to even load is if I comment out the session variable declarations. What happens when I do that, though, is once I submit the e-mail form, it directs me to the mailer script and never redirects me back to index.php like it should and does on my localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this which took me hours to solve with constant 500 errors when POSTing information from a form to PHPMailer in a separate file. My scripts all worked fine on my localhost but borked on a webserver.

It turned out to be a pathing issue. Localhost was checking the directories for the phpmailer files but the paths weren't working on the server.

My solution was to stop using composer and manually set the paths:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
include 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
include 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
include 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
```

The phpmailer directory was at the same level as the file containing the phpmailer settings. Cost me some lost sleep trying to solve :)